# Why my Eclipse requests for "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" and fails often

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse JavaEE IDE edition Indigo Release (build id:20110615-0604)
to develop Tomcat-based java web applications, 
and I've no plan to write anything about Web Service.

However, when I created a new Java web project in Eclipse,
it will automatically include a node named "JAX-WS Web Services" in the project explorer,
which I don't find a way to exclude.

And more inconveniently:
Everyday I first time launch my Eclipse and click to expand the project node 
in the project explorer, 
the whole Eclipse IDE will be stuck for a long while (about one or two minutes).

I thought it should be something wrong with the "JAX-WS Web Services" node.
So I used Fiddler to track the requests and responses.

I found that when I click to expand the project node, Eclipse will request for:

- (a) http: //java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
- (b) http: //java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/j2ee_1_4.xsd
- (c) http: //www.ibm.com/webservices/xsd/j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd
- (d) http: //www.ibm.com/software/info/webservices/xsd/j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd
- (e) http: //www-01.ibm.com/software/info/webservices/xsd/j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd
- (f) http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd

And the last one (f) will last for a long time to retrieve, 
and have a high failure rate (HTTP 504).
I believe this is the reason why Eclipse stuck.

I want to know:
How to fix or avoid this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried doing the same process, but I got a web project without JAX-WS services. puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an XML Schema that references it, like so:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
            schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
```

If so, download xml.xsd and make a local copy.  Change the import accordingly, perhaps like so:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
            schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>
```

Alternatively, change the import to the most current version of the file:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
            schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd"/>
```

Some have reported that this link is faster, but it is subject to becoming outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make an entry for that file in the XML Catalog, Window > Preferences > XML > XML Catalog, or enable caching in Window > Preferences > General > Network Connection > Cache